# How to show different icons in Crystal reports depending on the field value?

Tags: crystal-reports

We are using Crystal Report 12 in one of our projects. Currently I need to create report template which should show different icons based on the some field value.
That field contains a number, storing some kind of status  and I have several icons corresponding some statuses.

At the moment I can't figure out how to implement such a thing in Crystal Reports designer.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: If Heather answered your question, don't forget to check the green check mark :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing and hiding graphical objects in CR based on a formula is almost exactly like showing and hiding text labels based on certain criteria.

First, you need to add each icon to your report detail section by choosing the `Insert` menu, and then select `Picture...`

Once all your icons are inserted, you will need to edit the suppression formula by right-clicking on each icon and choosing `Format Graphic`.  On the first tab of the `Format Editor`, you have a `Suppress` option just like you do for other report objects.  Click on the formula button next to `Suppress` to add a suppression formula to the icon describing when it should be shown or hidden.

Comment: At the moment I am very busy with creating SQL query for my reports, but as soon as I return to creating report template I will check your solution and let you know if it worked or not.
But any way thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for the similar solution and this helped me. These steps works.

To display a particular picture, based on a column value, right click on picture> Format Graphic> Suppress (do not check)
And write formula, for example
ColorCode= '110'

(Based on column name ColorCode if column value is '110' I am displaying the picture)